# Как изменить масштаб интерфейса в Qt?

Tags: qt

Я работаю на линуксе, 2к монитор, и я не понимаю по какой причине, но у QtCreator здесь вырвиглазно маленький интфрейс (у самого редактора я имею в виду). Нужный пунктик в настройках найти не смог, в конфигах покопался - тоже ничего. Подскажите, что делать и как быть

Comment: `Инструменты -> Параметры -> Среда -> Язык (Галочка "Масштабировать при большом DPI")` это все, что есть.

Comment: неа, к сожалению не робит

Answer (score 2):

```
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5; qtcreator
```

Для увеличения подбираем значение больше 1 (1.5...)
Для уменьшения - менше 1 (0.7...)

Comment: На [Stack Overflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) на русском вопросы и ответы принято писать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш ответ на русский язык